# Using Apple Remote Desktop for managing iOS devices?

Tags: ios, remote-desktop, automation, apple-remote-desktop, mobile-device-management

Im currently evaluating using Apple Remote Desktop for multi laptop and desktop management. Can it also be used for iOS device management ?

We've got a range of devices - iPhone, iPads which are company owned. As well as staff who have their own iPhones which we install email, and specific business apps for them to use.

Its very tedious having to manually type all of the usernames and passwords into each device and app to get them setup is there a way i can do this from my desktop via Apple Remote Desktop or something similar ?

---

**UPDATE Dec 18**

Now that iOS 12 allows 3rd party remote management software like Bomgar and Teamviewer (see article [here](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-can-I-share-the-screen-on-my-iPad-iPhone-with-TeamViewer/ta-p/4734)) of iOS devices. (All be it view only, with no control)

Dose Apple Remote Desktop now offer the similar functionality including control ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use Apple Configurator to supervise iOS devices and then Meraki MDM to remotely manage them.  We push out a webclip and a global HTTP proxy setting to all devices this way.  Meraki MDM is free for up to 100 clients, after that you have to pay per client up to and including the first 100.  We were using the Apple OS X server app for awhile and while it does have some great features it is severely lacking in some key areas.  You get what you pay for.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Apple Remote Desktop does not support managing iOS devices at this time. The closest parallel would be [Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) which targets iOS automation in a similar manner to Remote Desktop.

I suggest investigating MDM solutions:

- Profile Manager in Apple's [OS X Server app](https://www.apple.com/osx/server/)
- [Casper Suite](http://www.jamfsoftware.com/products/casper-suite/) or [Bushel](http://www.bushel.com) by JAMF Software

These three options run either on any Mac you have or can be hosted in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Right now it is still not supported. The App hasn’t been updated in a year so I doubt support will be added as is it going a bit out of date.

Apple has some software for remote control mainly designed for education though:

https://www.apple.com/education/it/

While not the best solution it does offer Apple ID and iCloud control:

> Managed Apple IDs are created automatically when you connect Apple School Manager to your school’s roster data, and they give students access to iCloud Drive, iCloud Photo Library, Backup, Schoolwork, and Shared iPad. If you’re not using these services you can deploy iPad and Mac computers without an Apple ID. Students simply turn on the device and get to work, no sign-in required. If your school’s needs change, you can create Managed Apple IDs and distribute them to students later.

An alternative would be to use TeamViewer.

It can be downloaded here:

https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/mac-os/

This allows remote desktop control which can help enter passwords.

I don’t think you will get anywhere with Apple Remote Desktop Management though.

Answer (score 0):

No, [Apple Configurator](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) is Apple's solution for iOS management whereas Apple Remote Desktop is focused only on macOS clients. Server.app as well has profile manager for basic MDM functionality using the Apple Push Notification service. Even if your business / school has a few devices, reach out to Apple sales for help selecting an MDM whether you purchase the MDM Apple sells ([JAMF Now](https://www.jamf.com/lp/set-up-manage-and-protect-apple-devices-at-work/) / JAMF Now Plus or School / [JAMF Pro](https://www.jamf.com/lp/jamf-pro/)) or MDM Apple purchased outright (https://www.fleetsmith.com) they will help you select and evaluate an over the air solution to manage iOS if you don't want tethered management like [Ground Control](https://www.groundctl.com) and [Apple Configurator 2](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) offer.